# Hibernate, java.util.Map

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-jpa

Запутался с отображением Map в БД с использование Hibernate.

Весь код доступен [на битбакете](https://bitbucket.org/Mazuruk-O/poll_repo/src/dev_rabbitmq/poll-service/src/main/java/ua/edu/donnu/poll/poll_service/domain/). Возникает вопрос с классом [StudentChoise](https://bitbucket.org/Mazuruk-O/poll_repo/src/dev_rabbitmq/poll-service/src/main/java/ua/edu/donnu/poll/poll_service/domain/StudentChoise.java) (где Map< Long, Teacher> => <приоритетСтудента, преподаватель>), как правильно отобразить это в таблице, чтобы все оставалось нормализированным=)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я правильно понял, то **studentPriority** служит для ранжирования студентов преподавателями.

Создайте отдельную сущность **StudentPriority**. В нее добавьте внешние ключи типа many-to-one на Student, Teacher, а также обязательно создайте внешние ключи на эти связи. Добавьте поле типа Long, которое будет хранить собственно рейтинг.

Такая организация позволит избавиться от Map в StudentChoise, заменив его на List, а также удовлетворять требованиям нормализации.

Есть очень хорошая [статья](https://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-one-to-many) по этой теме.